# Is it possible to add an inderminate progressbar within a TableLayout?

Tags: android, progress-bar, tablelayout

I have a scroll view that contains Tablelayout as its Child view. Now while I am receving the data from the server I'd like to display a progress bar on the screen. When the data is received the progress bar must replaced by the tablerows.

I am able to achieve this partially. I add a progressbar view into the 3rd row (row 1 and 2 are headers) which has visibility gone once the data is received and tablerows are created.

The issue is that the progress bar appears at the top of the screen. To be consistent with the app, the progress bar must be in the middle of the screen as I have it on ListViews.

Here is the code snippet for Progressbar

```
`<TableRow
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"     android:gravity="center_horizontal">
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/list_progressbar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>   
</TableRow>
```

Comment: i think it's because you have it inside a scrollview. centering vertically probably doesn't work because the height isn't fixed? Why don't you use a progressdialog instead?

Comment: The rest of the app has an indeterminate progressbar and to keep the feel of the app consistent I was trying to keep it in the  center of the screen. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Have a TableLayout inside that put all TableRows as I hope you doing, including the one with the ProgressBar, now instead of going to replace.

You can achieve it other way, just make the View.GONE of the TableRow containing ProgressBar, and View.VISIBLE of TableRow which you want to show.

For example;

```
<TableLayout>
 <TableRow android:id="@+id/trheader1" .../>
 <TableRow android:id="@+id/trheader2" .../>
 <!-- keeping the visibility of gone //-->
 <TableRow android:id="@+id/trRow3" android:visibility="gone" .../>
 <!-- tr containing progressBar //-->
 <TableRow android:id="@+id/trprogressBar" .../>
</TableLayout>
```

as you recieve the data

```
((TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trRow3)).setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
((TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trprogressBar)).setVisibilty(View.GONE);
```

So, I hope this will work for you.
Thanks!